# How to make the terminal export a specific environment variable at every load?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I would like to run the script

```
PS1="┌─[\u@\h:]\n└─> "
```

In the terminal every time it's opened, but I can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `export PS1="┌─[\u@\h:]\n└─> "` at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file.

This should get run automatically with each terminal session, assuming your terminal uses `bash` and not `zsh` or something else

Comment: You sir, are a god.

Comment: Heh.  You can call me a God if you want, @Zelpa, but I'm just a Lord.  A Lord of Time.  :P  That, and `~/.bashrc` is the local file where various things are done for an individual user whenever bash gets launched, including but not limited to setting PS1.